# Experiment to create node in kubernetes cluster(AKS) using chaos toolkit

Tags: chaos, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am trying to create an experiment for creating a node using chaostoolkit

### yaml for experiment

```
version: 1.0.0
title: What happens if we create a node
description: All the instances are distributed among healthy nodes and the applications are healthy
tags:
- k8s
- deployment
- node
steady-state-hypothesis:
  title: Nodes are indestructible
  probes:
  - name: all-apps-are-healthy
    type: probe
    tolerance: true
    provider:
      type: python
      func: all_microservices_healthy
      module: chaosk8s.probes
      arguments:
        ns: qs-aks-dev
method:
- type: action
  name: create-node
  provider:
    type: python
    func: create_node
    module: chaosk8s.node.actions
  pauses:
    after: 10
~
~
```

### getting below error while executing the experiment

```
Action: create-node
[2021-11-09 13:15:17 ERROR]   => failed: chaoslib.exceptions.ActivityFailed: Creating new node failed: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Node \"\" is invalid: metadata.name: Required value: name or generateName is required","reason":"Invalid","details":{"kind":"Node","causes":[{"reason":"FieldValueRequired","message":"Required value: name or generateName is required","field":"metadata.name"}]},"code":422}
```

can anybody please help me to write this experiment

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using it the right way but

```
name: create-node
provider:
  func: create_node
  module: chaosk8s.node.actions
  type: python
type: action
```

however, looks like there could be chances it wont work with AKS as mentioned.

> Due to the way things work on certain cloud providers, you won't be
> able to use this meaningfully on them. For instance on GCE, this will
> likely fail.

Read more at : https://github.com/chaostoolkit/chaostoolkit-documentation/blob/master/sources/drivers/kubernetes.md#create_node